# adb connection problem on Kubuntu 13.04 x64

Tags: android, kubuntu

I'm facing a problem with ABD connection under Kubuntu 13.04 x64. Every time I try to push/pull/shell ls the adb disconnects from device. I tried the following solutions:

1. Added device ID into .android/adb_usb.ini but nothing helped
2. Added new udev rule and also nothing helped
3. Flashed the ROM and nothing helped
4. I re-installed my Kubuntu 13.04 x64

Some notes :

- USB Debugging activated
- Device is Prestigio PMP5080BRU (Rooted) - Android Gingerbread 2.3.1
- I'm using the latest Android SDK available on official web site
- The ADB works very well on Windows 7 x64
- Even when ADB disconnects, I still can see device via **lsusb**
  command
- ia32-libs already installed on the system
- jdk and jre installed on the system and works as expected
- Paths configured and working properly
- ADB works as expected with my Samsung Galaxy S II (Jelly Bean 4.1.2 -
  Stock)
- I put my question here, because it seems I got a problem in Linux,
  as my other device works on Kubuntu

dmesg :

```
[ 5571.640498] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[ 5571.657013] usb 3-2: config 1 interface 1 altsetting 0 bulk endpoint 0x83 has invalid maxpacket 64
[ 5571.657426] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bb4, idProduct=0c02
[ 5571.657433] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5571.657436] usb 3-2: Product: rk2918
[ 5571.657439] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: RockChip
[ 5571.657442] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
[ 5571.664067] scsi13 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[ 5572.659163] scsi 13:0:0:0: Direct-Access     PMP5080B                  0100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 5572.659453] scsi 13:0:0:1: Direct-Access     PMP5080B                  0100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 5572.661211] sd 13:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 5572.661525] sd 13:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 5572.662492] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 5572.662947] sd 13:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Any one got an idea?
Regards,,,

Comment: What does `modinfo rk2918` show?

Comment: ERROR: Module rk2918 not found.

Comment: What is the Product, if you connect your S II? Can you do a modinfo on that?